# Google chart. Fixed position for a certain period of time

Tags: javascript, date, charts, google-visualization

I ran into a couple of problems when creating a Google chart, I ask you to help me:

1. I can't set the initial position of the chart on the dates of the current week.
2. In this regard, when you click on the filter by date button, an error occurs in the console - "Cannot read property 'start' of undefined" The chart is drawn only after selecting the interval on the range slider

Here is my code:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['controls', 'lineChart']
  }).then(function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('date', '');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Mgr');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Glencore Т');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Cargill');
      data.addColumn('number', 'OZK');
  
      data.addRows([
          [new Date(2021,01,13), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,01,14), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,01,15), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,01,16), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,01,17), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,01,18), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,01,19), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,01,20), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,01,21), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,01,22), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
  
          [new Date(2021,02,03), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,02,05), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,02,06), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,02,10), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,02,17), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,02,23), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
  
          [new Date(2021,03,02), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,03,04), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,03,08), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,03,11), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,03,22), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          
          [new Date(2021,04,03), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,04,05), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,04,06), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,04,10), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,04,17), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,04,23), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
  
          [new Date(2021,05,03), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,05,05), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,05,06), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,05,10), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,05,17), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,05,23), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
  
          [new Date(2021,06,03), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,06,05), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,06,06), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,06,10), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,06,17), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,06,23), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
  
          [new Date(2021,07,26), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,07,27), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,07,28), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,07,29), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,07,30), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,07,31), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
  
          [new Date(2021,08,01), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,08,12), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,08,03), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
  
          [new Date(2021,09,03), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,09,05), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,09,06), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,09,10), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,09,17), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,09,23), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
  
          [new Date(2021,10,03), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,10,05), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,10,06), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,10,10), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,10,17), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,10,23), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
  
          [new Date(2021,11,03), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,11,05), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,11,06), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,11,10), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,11,17), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,11,23), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
  
          [new Date(2021,12,03), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,12,05), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,12,06), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,12,10), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,12,17), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
          [new Date(2021,12,23), Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000, Math.random() * 10000],
      ]);
  
    var rangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
      containerId: 'filter-range',
      options: {
        filterColumnIndex: 0,
        ui: {
          chartType: 'LineChart',
          chartOptions: {
            chartArea: {
              width: '100%',
              left: 36,
              right: 18
            },
            height: 72
          }
        }
      }
    });
  
    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'LineChart',
      containerId: 'chart-area',
      options: {
        legend: {
          alignment: 'end',
          position: 'top'
        },
        animation: {
          duration: 500,
          easing: 'in',
          startup: true
        },
        chartArea: {
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%',
          top: 36,
          left: 36,
          right: 18,
          bottom: 36
        }
      }
    });
  
    let sortButton = document.getElementsByClassName('graph-block__btn') || false;
    

    for (var i in sortButton) {
        sortButton[i].onclick = function(sender) {
        const active = document.querySelector(".active");
        if (active) {
            active.classList.remove("active");
        }
        this.classList.add("active");

        var currentRange = rangeFilter.getState();
        visibleRange = parseInt(sender.target.getAttribute('data-range'));
        if (isNaN(visibleRange)) {
        rangeFilter.setState(null);
        } else {
        rangeFilter.setState({
            range: {
                start: currentRange.range.start,
                end: new Date(currentRange.range.start.getTime() + visibleRange)
                }
            });
        }
        rangeFilter.draw();
        };
    }
  
    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));
    dashboard.bind(rangeFilter, chart);
    dashboard.draw(data);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="graph-block__chart" id="dashboard">
    <div id="filter-range" ></div>
    <div class="graph-block__control-list" id="range-buttons">
        <button class="graph-block__btn active" data-range="604800000">Week</button>

        <button class="graph-block__btn" data-range="2592000000">Month</button>

        <button class="graph-block__btn" data-range="7776000000">3 Month</button>

        <button class="graph-block__btn" data-range="15552000000">6 Month</button>

        <button class="graph-block__btn" data-range="31104000000">1 Year</button>
    </div>
    <div id="categoryFilter_div"></div>
    <div id="chart-area" style="width: 100%; height: 520px"></div>
</div>
```

I would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, I did not notice an error in initialization (it was necessary to change the linechart to corechart)